# Ruby / Pundit -> user.owner_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

I saw below in the pundit documentation and was wondering if that is part of some ruby or pundit magic based on user_id being present in a given model.
Or if it's just something they used to get a point across
https://github.com/varvet/pundit

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this is just an example of the use of a function in the user that you have to implement yourself.

For example:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   ...

   def owner_of?(resource)
      self.id == resource.user.id
   end

   ...
end
```

First condition `user.admin?` is usable thanks to the enum in the user class. Rails provide dynamic methods to verify the role of a particular user

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   ...
   enum role: [ 
      :admin,
      :moderator,
      :editor
   ]
   ...
end
```

This makes the methods available on the user object:

```
user.admin?
user.moderator?
user.editor?
```